# Remove minDate/maxDate limits in jQuery UI Datepicker

Tags: jquery-ui-datepicker, date-range, limits, maxdate, mindate

A simple issue, but I can't seem to find the answer.

I've limited the date range in jQuery Datepicker:

```js
$( "#MyDatepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", new Date())
```

Is there a way to remove all restrictions for date range?

Comment: What do you mean by removing all restrictions? You just have set min date, now you want to remove it?

Comment: yes, i want to set selectable date range back to unlimited

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try this `$( "#MyDatepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", null)`.

From JQuery documentation about datepicker minDate option

> Set a minimum selectable date via a Date object or as a string in the current dateFormat, or a number of days from today (e.g. +7) or a string of values and periods ('y' for years, 'm' for months, 'w' for weeks, 'd' for days, e.g. '-1y -1m'), or null for no limit.

Answer (score -1):

Using [this](http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html) jQuery datepick, what about

```
$(selector).datepick();
```